# Why ActivatedRoute.queryParams is not working in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, query-string, angular-activatedroute

I am using routing in my Angular app.

I have bellow route in my routing module.

```
{
    path: 'user/:name',
    component: UserComponent,
}
```

I am using `queryParams` of `ActivatedRoute` to get name from route. this is my code.

```
this.activatedRout.queryParams.subscribe( params => {

  this.user_name = params['name'];

});
```

But `params` are undefined. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For understanding, you have a route look like **`user/karthik?style=awesome`** for example, the part **`karthik`** is the param **`:name`** , while you need **`style=awesome`**, which is the query param, that's why it is `undefined`.

If your intend is to subscribe for params changes, use **`paramMap`**, not **`queryParam`**.

```
this.activatedRout.paramMap.subscribe( params => {
 this.name = params['params']['name']
});
```

Or you can use **`params`** :

```
this.activatedRout.params.subscribe( params => {
 this.name = params['name'];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know there's an accepted answer here but it's missing a crucial detail about what `queryParams` is. Here are my notes:

```
// { path: 'user/:name'...

// access route params from router ie 'joe' from URL example.com/user/joe
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params); // access the user name param 
});

// map your router parameter values
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    // this.name = params['params']['name']
});

// access URL query parameters ie. example.com/?x=7680&y=4320
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `params` not `queryParams`

`this.activatedRout.params.subscribe( params =>{this.user_name = params['name'];});`

Answer (score 0):

```
this.activatedRout.params.subscribe(({name}) => {
    this.user_name = name;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Access URL query parameters ie. http://localhost:4200/products?category=bread

```
route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {
    this.category = params['category'];
    console.log(this.category);
});
```